# Laplacian on a manifold with two boundary components

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, 3-manifolds, linear-pde, laplacian

I am interested in the Laplace equation on knot complements. The full complement of a knot $K$ is in $S^3$, but for compactness, we delete an open tubular neighborhood around $K$. The Laplace PDE on $S^3 - K$ with Dirichlet conditions on the boundary torus has only trivial constant solutions. However, I want to model electrostatic charge of a knot in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and since the potential goes to zero at infinity, we can delete an open ball around the point at infinity. Thus our boundary domain has two boundary components: a torus and an $S^2$. Close to the knot, the potential is large, and far away, the potential is small. So we have the PDE $\Delta \Phi =0$ and the boundary conditions that $\Phi$ is a positive constant $c_1$ on the boundary torus and another positive constant $c_2$ on the boundary sphere with $c_1 > c_2$.

Are there any references for solving PDEs of this form, where the boundary is broken into two disjoint components and the conditions are that the solution must take differing constants on them?

Comment: What is it that you wish to know? That a solution exists, is unique, and has certain regularity? Or something else?

Comment: I already have existence, but I want to know about uniqueness and about the critical sets of the solutions.

Comment: Uniqueness follows immediately from the maximum principle, no?

Comment: How so? But I need to know more than just existence and uniqueness.

Comment: Uniqueness holds as long as you know the value on all boundary components. This is typically explained in electrodynamics books (such as Griffiths') which is what your question is about.